# Adding a percent of noise to a GDI+ Bitmap is failing

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, std

I've written this code that generates a vector of pixels to set with "noise".  The problem is no matter what I do, I only get a NW-SE line.  Not random dots.  What am I doing wrong?

```
void CPixelNoiseGenerator::GenerateRandomNoise(NoiseAmount eNoiseAmount, UINT nNoiseAmount, UINT nWidth, UINT nHeight, std::vector<CPoint>& vecPoints)
{
    unsigned long long nNumPixels = nWidth * nHeight, nNumNoisePixels = 0;
    nNumNoisePixels = (nNumPixels * nNoiseAmount) / 100;
    vecPoints.clear();

    if (nNumNoisePixels == 0)
        return;

    UINT nWidthDistance = (nWidth * nNoiseAmount) / 100, nHeightDistance = (nHeight * nNoiseAmount) / 100;

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 generator(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> distribution(0.0, (nWidth < nHeight ? nHeightDistance : nWidthDistance) * 1.0);
    auto dice = std::bind(distribution, generator);

    do
    {
        for(UINT x = 0; x < nWidth; x += nWidthDistance)
            for (UINT y = 0; y < nHeight; y += nHeightDistance)
            {
                CPoint pt; // = GetRandomPointOnDesign(nWidth, nHeight, generator);
                pt.x = x + distribution(generator);
                pt.y = y + distribution(generator);
                vecPoints.push_back(pt);
            }
    } while (vecPoints.size() <= nNumNoisePixels);

}
```

Comment: You are using integer arithmetic, which may or may not yield the desired result, depending on the values of `nWidth`, `nHeight`, and `nNoiseAmount`. Check to see if the results are what you actually want. If not, you can either use floating point math, or call `MulDiv` that does.

Comment: Thanks.  I may change that, although I realized later (and embarrassingly) that when I called SetPixel I was passing X twice (SetPixel(x, x, COLORREF) rather than SetPixel(x, y, COLORREF).  Daft!  So the code works, but not nearly as well as PSP's Add Noise function

Comment: `SetPixel` is horribly slow. Better get a pointer to the destination bitmap's pixel data and operate on that.